# Relatively compact Family of Polynomials

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Can someone please help me to solve this problem:

For $r\in \mathbb{N}$ ,we note :

$E_r$={$P\in \mathbb{R}[x_1,x_2,...,x_d] $ such that $deg P\le r$ } 
And for  $P\in E_r$ we define the function $R_P:\mathbb{R}^d \rightarrow
\mathbb{R}$

by:
$R_P(x)=\sum_{1\le|\alpha|\le r} |\partial_x^{\alpha}P(x)|^{\frac{1}{|\alpha|}} $

By using the Taylor formula for a polynômial given by:

$P(x_0+t)=\sum_{|\alpha |\le deg P} \frac{\partial_x^{(\alpha)} P(x_0)}{\alpha !} t^{\alpha }$

I want to show that  the family of polynomials $(P(x_0+\frac{x}{R_P(x_0)})-P(x_0))_{x_0\in \mathbb{R}^d,P\in E_r}$ is relatively compact in $\mathbb{R}[x_1,x_2,...,x_d]$ with the  $L^{\infty}(R^d)$ norme .
Thanks

Comment: By définition, $A=(P(x_0+\frac{x}{R_P(x_0)})-P(x_0))_{x_0\in \mathbb{R}^d,P\in E_r}$ subspace of $E=\mathbb{R}[x_1,x_2,...,x_d]$ is  relatviely compact if from every sequence of  A we can extact a  convergente sequence , which has a limit in $E$
But i can't apply the definition here .Can someone help?

Comment: By using tne Taylor formula we have:$P(x_0+\frac{x}{R_P(x_0)})-P(x_0)=\sum_{1\le|\alpha|\le r} \frac{\partial_x^{\alpha}P(x_0)}{\alpha !}(\frac{x}{R_P(x_0)})^{\alpha}$